# How can I send variable value with To Instrument Simulink block?

Tags: matlab, simulink, visa

I am using an external PSU (RIGOL DP832) and I would like to set the voltage and current using simulink but I am not able to do it with simulink.

I am using the Instrument Toolbox and the Support Package for Keysight IO Libraries and VISA Interface. For matlab it is straight forward, this is the code

```
PSU = visadevlist();
vi = visa('agilent',PSU{1,1});

fopen(vi);
fprintf(vi, ':INST CH2'); 
fprintf(vi, ':VOLT 27.3');
fclose(vi);
```

but with simulink I am not able to send the value of a variable to the PSU. I am using the To Instrument block, and this is my simple simulink diagram,

[image]

and these are my properties

[image]

Any idea how to do this? I am also open to other alternatives, but I need parametric input for simulink

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the block but having read the documentation I'd suggest the following

Change your command to

```
':VOLT '
```

The block will then add the value from the inport of the block to the end of the above command.

In your example you've added the voltage as a fixed value in the command string.